# CKEditor.Text is giving HTMLEncoded Output in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use CKEditor into my ASP.NET Application. I got a good resource as follows
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/532164/How-to-Integrate-CKEditor-with-ASP-NET
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/455129/Rich-Text-Editor-with-ASP-NET

I want  to set the CKEditor Text without losing its formatting (bold, Italics etc..) into a multiline Textbox. So, I am trying the following code.

```
string str = this.CKEditor1.Text;
TextBox1.Text = str;
```

Thus its giving me a html encoded Output as follows

```
<p>dfgdfgfdgdfgdfgdf<strong>gdf</strong></p>
```

But I don't want to have those tags around but formatting should be preserved. I tried using HTMLEncode and HTMLDecode, Also used `this.CKEditor1.HtmlEncodeOutput = false;` but of no avail.

Is there any other way I can save the text as it is without losing formatting into my Textbox?

I know textboxes are not meant for storing formatted html outputs but I have to store this(Comments) along with a formatting in a text box(for History) in my Application. Previously they were using Plain text boxes for both comments and History. Now richtext editing is needed and hence we are tying to go this way. Any other good approaches and suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

No, a `Textbox` cant display formatted values. That is why you have the CKEditor.
You can still store the html formated values in the database and display them (formatted) in for example a `Label`